# If statement working in a strange way

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working with an if loop, which ended up working in a very strange way. Here is how the code is structured:

```
for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(0, M):
        if ((A - B[j]) == 0):
            print i, f[j]
            [...]
            print 'test'
```

`f[j]` is only defined in if `((A - B[j]) == 0)`. When I run the script, at first it prints both `i, f[j]` and `test` and then, when `((A - B[j]) == 0)` is not true anymore, it only prints `test`.

What should I do to make the script run properly?

Comment: Check if you are mixing spaces and tabs in your indentation.

Comment: Are you sure your code is indented correctly?

Comment: Your code has wrong syntax, you miss colons at the end of 'for' statement.

Comment: Can you post some input and expected output?
Also, you have inconsistent indentation, second line is indented 2 spaces, third 5 spaces, the rest is indented 8 spaces.

Comment: interjay, BrenBarn: well spotted, some of the lines were not indented correctly ;-) m.wasowski: I fixed the colons in the pseudo code

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. You have an if *statement* in two for *loops*.  There is no such thing as an "if loop". If is a conditional branch, loops repeat an action. They are very different control structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me as you seem to expect, after correcting syntax and indentation:

```
A = 3
B = range(10)
f = range(10)

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        if (A == B[j]):
        # if ((A - B[j]) == 0):
            print i, f[j]
            print 'test'
```

-- Output --

```
0 3
test
1 3
test
2 3
test
3 3
test
4 3
test
5 3
test
6 3
test
7 3
test
8 3
test
9 3
```